# Convert text to integer and if higher than 50 alert

Tags: javascript

On our current website that is hosted offsite via another company it is all done with .NET, I simply have access to HTML, JS, and CSS files to edit. A lot of data is output on the page via tokens. On our web page we have a weight token, it grabs the items weight and outputs it between a span tag. So if you're viewing the source it'll show the following:

```
<span id="order_summary_weight">78.000000 lbs</span>
```

The token by default outputs the lbs. What I need to do is have javascript grab the 78.000000, convert it to an integer I'm assuming and if that integer, in this case 78.000000 is greater than 50.000000 I'd like it append a line after the 78.000000 lbs to say "Your weight total is over 50 lbs, we will contact you directly with a shipping charge." Understand some weight totals may be as small as 0.010000

I'm coming to you fine folks here because I am at a complete lost where to start in this endeavor.

Comment: does the site use XMLHttpRequests to update the weight?

Comment: The fact that he said "viewing the source" (as opposed to "inspect element") indicates that it's coming along with the original request instead of via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ? :

html :

```
<div class="wrap">
    <span class="price" id="order_summary_weight">78.000000 lbs</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="wrap">
    <span class="price" id="order_summary">50.000000 lbs</span>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('.wrap').each(function(){
    var price = $(this).find('.price').text();
    price = price.replace(' lbs', '');
    price = parseInt(price);

    if(price > 50){
        $(this).append('<div class="alert">Your weight total is over 50 lbs, we will contact you directly with a shipping charge.</div>');
    }
});
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/w3qg4/1/**

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWeight()
  {
  var x=document.getElementById("order_summary_weight");
  if(x > 50){
      alert("Your weight total is over 50 lbs, we will contact you directly with a shipping charge. Understand some weight totals may be as small as 0.010000");
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not perfect, but it gives you an idea of where to start and you can make it your own.

Comment: Thanks Chris, missed a quote